# How to setup Google Analytics with a SSG web page built with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, next.js

I tried to apply Google Analytics to my web page, but no access is reflected on GA console.

I referenced this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-analytics
Is this setup only for SSR, not for SSG?

If that is the case, how can I setup GA to my SSG website? Is it possible in the first place?

Comment: That setup should work for SSG too. Can you see the GA request being sent in the `Network` tab in the dev tools? Is your tracking ID properly setup?

Comment: One of the browser extensions seemed to block the access to GA. Disabling it solved the issue. Thank you for your support :)